# Can't make cookies work for subdomain

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies, subdomain

**Update: looks like it didn't work because of local machine hosting, particularly short domain names used (like `'.t'`).
The same code on remote server with actual (real-life) domain names usage works fine.**

There are two domains (the root and it's sub one) both running looking at the same webserver's directory, thus, working on the exact same scripts.
(I have Apache/PHP run on Windows XP on a home computer, so I choose to use short names for the local hosts - 't' and 'a.t' respectively).

```
session_set_cookie_params(
          24*3600, // 24 hours 
          '/',     // all paths
          '.t',    // 't' and all sub-domains
          FALSE,   // not secure
          FALSE    // not http-only
     ); 

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 't') 
    setcookie(
            'test',           // cookie name
            'yes',            // cookie value
            time() + 24*3600, // expires after 24 hours
            '/',              // all paths
            '.t',             // t and all subdomains
            FALSE,            // not secure
            FALSE             // not http-only
        );

echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '<br>';

print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Here what I have for the root local host:

```
t 
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 23lhahncni8ekeqj3j02u7qlq5 [test] => yes )
```

and for the subdomain:

```
a.t 
Array ( )
```

As you can see, the $_COOKIE array for the subdomain is empty, although corresponding cookies can be seen by the browser (Firebug, to be exact - I can see those two cookies in the tab where subdomain's page is opened).
I can't figure out why is that happening.

I need to access $_COOKIE[test] for both domains. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params` only sets options for the session cookie, not for cookies created with `setcookie()`.

Comment: I have the feeling that you're not the first one with this problem so I wonder a little why you open a new question about that topic.

Comment: @hakre, because I didn't find an answer that works for me. I tried some other code (which is similar to posted here earlier) but it still doesn't work - see the top message (I edited).

Comment: @hakre, actually the post which you (or someone else) pointed out as a duplicate of, has to deal with different webservers and, furthermore, some python stuff. I have the exact same script and no different webservers (not to say I have no python or any other thing involved). So, while I did find it before posting my one, I didn't even consider this one be useful for me.

Comment: @hakre, I think the whole issue is clear from the code cited for any person with appropriate level of PHP knowledge. I still insist the question is not a duplicate because the issue came out to be related to local machine hosting and artificial domain names used (what I brought in to the question text in my recent edit), which are not matched by any question on this site. With that said, I finally made it work on one of my remote environments, which I am satisfied with, so I will not do any further research and assume the case closed. _All I claim now is taking off the duplicate tag_.

Comment: @1234ru: Just getting some votes to get your question re-open. I just have seen your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the domain in the call to `setcookie()`:

```
setcookie('test', 'yes', 0, '/', '.t');
```

`session_set_cookie_params()` only sets the options for the cookie used to save `$_SESSION`, not cookies set using `setcookie`.

Comment: Hm.. Didn't think about it. Really, it is a session cookie. But then at least the session cookie (which is PHPSESSID) should be visible. And it's not. I modified the code adding parameters to setcookie() (see the top message - I edited) and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What is the actual domain you specified in `setcookie`? Did it really have just one component like `.t`? Browsers won't let you set a cookie on a top-level domain like that.

Comment: you were right. It really has to do with such artificial short domain names. I ran the code in an environment with normal domain names used and it works fine. Thank you for contribution.